# my lumia 625 got stuck in update windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nokia-lumia-625

I used windows insider app; it said updates are available for my phone.

But the update process is now perpetually stuck at 0%. I see this message:
"phone update
Update status

---

Downloading updates 0%"

This message always remains whenever I visit the phone update screen (has been stuck for the last 3 days!).
The progress bar is stuck at 0% - it isn't downloading any updates or making any progress at all.

There is no option on the screen to cancel this update process and to start again.

The only two options below the progress indicator bar are two tick boxes:
"[ ] Tell me when updates are available for my phone" and "[ ] Automatically download updates if my data settings allow it".

I have tried checking and un-checking these boxes; I've also tried turning off/on the WiFi and Data Connection.
I even shut off the phone completely, but when I turn it back on and go to Settings > Phone Update, it's still stuck on "Downloading updates 0%" !!

I am able to browse the Internet on the phone. WiFi and regular data connection are both working fine.even after I try to connect in different WiFi network...bt I stuck..plz help me..

Comment: If you turn Airplane mode On and restart the phone does the problem persist?

Comment: Yes its got stuck...i just turn the airplane mode on & restart the phone but same problem repeat...

Comment: So it started to "Download" even though it was in Airplane Mode? I think the only thing you can try is a reset now.

Comment: Now there is a download about 5%...bt already it stuck for 1hr....

Comment: Did you manage to finish the download?

Comment: Please dont try to download in lumia 625, i tried it and got stucked up after installing windows 10 successfully, entire function will not be run in lumia 625

Comment: I have the same problem on my 920. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Turn Battery saver  off ;) it worked on my phone 920 :)

In this discussion [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia/update-bug-stuck-at-0/8d9fe5b4-a3ea-4756-a879-21c20a83343e?auth=1) in Microsoft community, 42 people have found that turning off battery saver was helpful.

> Thanks cjlim. Figured out the problem, it was the Battery Saver. I
>   turned off battery saver then re-booted the phone as you said. Updated
>   successfully. Thx