# problem to get W10 on my lumia 930

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-930, windows-10-upgrade

I have bought a new Lumia 930 (it's EE version but network unlocked)
the phone update showed some language support update, so I tried installing it. The problem is that the update download is stuck at 0% and I'm not able to cancel it. Now I want to update my phone to W10 but the when I open phone update, it's constantly showing 'downloading update' but it's stuck at 0% from 3 days.
I downloaded windows upgrade advisor, it says W10 is available.
So please help me install W10 on my NL930.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9351/106

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps one by one:

1. Try updating via WI-Fi. Some updates require Wi-Fi connection to work and will not download on Mobile data.
2. Make sure you have enough free space on phone. If not try moving apps and photos to SD card.
3. Turn off the battery saver if it is turned on. As noted 
   , 42 people have found this helpful.

> Thanks cjlim. Figured out the problem, it was the Battery Saver. I
>   turned off battery saver then re-booted the phone as you said. Updated
>   successfully. Thx

4. Try removing your SD card. (This has helped when updates are struck at spinning gears)
5. If nothing works out perform a Hard Reset. It will surely solve your problem but you will loose all your data on phone.

If you have decided to perform a hard reset, use the [Transfer my Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/Transfer-my-Data/9WZDNCRFJ3DR) app by Microsoft and Export all your data to SDcard. Remove your SDcard and proceed with Hard Reset.

See this answer here on [how to perform a Hard reset](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13338/18061).

**References:**

1. [Update Bug Stuck at 0% - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia/update-bug-stuck-at-0/8d9fe5b4-a3ea-4756-a879-21c20a83343e?auth=1)
2. [Phone Struck at Installing OS update - WP Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8865/phone-stuck-installing-an-os-update)
3. [Windows phone 8.1 stuck in spinning wheels -Cybercultura.com](http://www.cybercultura.com/2014/08/21/windows-phone-81-stuck-in-spinning-wheels-problem/)
4. [How to perform Hard Reset - WP Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13338/18061)

Comment: thank you very much!! the language support was downloaded and now i've got W10 update without any extra actions... may be there was something wrong with source servers, so i the download was never initiated... ironically everything was fine right after i asked my question here... but thank you anyway...

Comment: @KaranGuruprasad Glad to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the W10m version you have, you might need to become an insider momentously to make the download.

This was described somewhere in the Windows blog and it is fixed by now, but you can also try this, specially if you suspect that your Windows is not updated